# USE SQL "Where Column IN(val1, val2, val3)" In JasperReports

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have a Jasper Report Which takes the Where Clause as Parameter:

The where clause i pass is:

```
WHERE vw.computer_number IN ("12635, 34657, 35477")
```

When i preview the report in IReport it returns all 3 pages where each page id = computer_number specified in IN().

But when i pass the same in a HashMap as Parameter it returns only 1 page with the first computer number.

Parameter Definition:

```
<parameter name="paySlipWhereClause" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false"> 
  <defaultValueExpression>
    <![CDATA[" Where vw.computer_number IN(12635, 34657, 35477)"]]>
  </defaultValueExpression> 
</parameter>
```

Java code building the parameter value:

```
String computer_numbers[] = {"12635", "34657", "3547"}; 
String computer_nos = ""; 
for (int i = 0; i < computer_numbers.length; i++) { 
  computer_nos = computer_nos + "," + computer_numbers[i]; 
} 
String comp_numbers = computer_nos.replaceFirst(",", ""); 
HashMap param = new java.util.HashMap<String, String>(); 
param.put("payroll_tag", payroll_tag); 
//" WHERE vw.computer_number IN (29875,31775,29929)" 
param.put("paySlipWhereClause", "WHERE vw.computer_number IN (" + comp_numbers + ")");
```

Comment: Please specify the portion of the jrxml which contains the db query and the portion which contains the parameter definition. Thanks.

Comment: `<parameter name="paySlipWhereClause" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
  <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[" Where vw.computer_number IN(12635, 34657, 35477)". In my code i Use String builder to append the comma separated computer_number, then i pass the parameter
]]></defaultValueExpression>
 </parameter>`

Comment: AND The java Code does like this: `String computer_numbers[] = {"12635", "34657", "3547"}; String computer_nos = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < computer_numbers.length; i++) {
            computer_nos = computer_nos + "," + computer_numbers[i];
        }
        String comp_numbers = computer_nos.replaceFirst(",", "");

        HashMap param = new java.util.HashMap<String, String>();
        param.put("payroll_tag", payroll_tag);
        //" WHERE vw.computer_number IN (29875,31775,29929)"
        
        param.put("paySlipWhereClause", "WHERE vw.computer_number IN (" + comp_numbers + ")");`

Comment: M. Hussaini I added the code to you just posted in a comment to the actual question. Also you still did not post the portion of the jrxml that has the db query as was requested by @Jeremy. In the future, long blocks of code do not belong in comments, they just are not readable. It is important to keep in mind that when asking strangers for help, that you want to make it as easy as possible for them to do so. It just gets you better results in the end.

Comment: Also the where clause you say you pass in does not look right. It will not look like 3 numbers, but as 1 String to the database. Is that a typo in your question? What is the actual value you use for the parameter in iReport?

Comment: Thanks for your reply: The actual value i pass as the Parameter is: "Where vw.computer_number IN(12635, 34657, 35477)"

Comment: @M.Hussaini You should post the ***queryString*** expression from your jrxml file. Did you pass the `param` Map to the report (via the **JasperFillManager** class or something similar)?

Comment: @M.Hussaini  You can use the `$X{IN, <column_name>, <parameter_name>}` expression. For more details you can read [this post](http://jasperforge.org/uploads/publish/jasperreportswebsite/trunk/sample.reference/query/index.html#query).